# problems with sql hours ( postgresql )

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

show data from travel where time is less than 18:30:

---

```
insert into schedules(code, datetime, street)
values('004',TO_DATE('02/01/15 17:00','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI'),'street1');

insert into schedules(code, datetime, street)
values('004',TO_DATE('02/01/15 17:30','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI'),'street2');

insert into schedules(code, datetime, street)
values('004',TO_DATE('02/01/15 18:00','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI'),'street3')
```

---

```
insert into schedules(code, datetime, street)
values('005',TO_DATE('01/01/15 18:00','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI'),'street4');

insert into schedules(code, datetime, street)
values('005',TO_DATE('01/01/15 18:30','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI'),'street5');

insert into schedules(code, datetime, street)
values('005',TO_DATE('01/01/15 20:00','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI'),'street6')
```

---

This query:

```
select * 
from schedules where TO_CHAR(datetime,'HH24:MI')<'18:30');
```

shows all rows.

Comment: Show the query you've tried

Comment: select *            
from schedules
where TO_CHAR(datetime,'HH24:MI')<'18:30');

Comment: Don't post code in comments. **Edit** your question (I have done that for you for now, but please remember the next time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is, that you are storing the data incorrectly.

This:

> ```
> insert into schedules(code, datetime, street)
> values ('005',TO_DATE('01/01/15 20:00','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI'),'street6')
> ```

inserts a `DATE` value, **without** a  time into the table (because `to_date()` returns a `date`, not a `timestamp`)

If you want to store a *real* timestamp value (date & time), you need to use `to_timestamp()` or an ANSI timestamp literal:

```
insert into schedules(code, datetime, street)
values ('005',to_timestamp('01/01/15 20:00','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI'),'street6');
```

I personally prefer to use ANSI timestamp literals:

```
insert into schedules(code, datetime, street)
values ('005',timestamp '2015-01-01 20:00:00','street6');
```

---

To retrieve rows base on **only** the time, you should compare `time` values, **not** strings.

Assuming `datetime` is defined as a `timestamp` column (and **not* as a `date` as you can get all schedules before 18:30 using this:

```
select *
from schedules
where datetime::time < time '18:30'
```

The expression `datetime::time` will extract **only** the time part of the timestamp as a "real" time value, not as a string, which can be compared to a proper time literal

Comment: Thank you very much. I am so grateful for you hurry response.